# How to list out manually searched network operator in out list view?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using the below code to open the **NetworkSettings** into the app for getting the available list, then using the details to change the Network.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
            startActivity(intent);
```

But it's not working for Nexus Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
```

or:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

More [info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) on how to open different Settings.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS)); It's for open Access Point Names. But I have to open the Preferred Network

Comment: Have a look the the [available constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#constants) for Settings.

Comment: I have referred and tried the code but its open the NetworkSettings  & etc., Expect the Preferred NetworkMode.